# Why do my single quotes vanish on substitution with sed

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

What is the right command for:

```bash
sudo sed -i '/, false);/adefine( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );' /var/www/html/wp-config.php
```

The result is:

```
define( WP_MEMORY_LIMIT, 64M );
```

instead of the desired:

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );
```

Comment: What happens here, is that the second single-quote ends the quotation, and `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` just goes as an unquoted string to sed. No problem with that, since it's just non-special characters. But the quotes do not nest. But you could put double-quotes(`"`) inside single-quotes(`'`) and the other way around.

Comment: Hint: look at the automatic coloring of the code in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try double quotes for the outer ones:

```bash
sed -i "/, false);/adefine( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );"
```

Comment: @victor212 If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.